# How can i create PDF Viewer in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Hi i need to implement PDF viewer in my application.

I able to launch pdf file in third party applications(Adobe reader ..etc) but i need to launch pdf file with in the application not outside of the application.

Is there any API for it ?

Could any one advise me. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries that provide an embedded PDF Viewer for your application.

For example [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/)

Comment: it seems MuPDF has nothing for WP Silverlight apps. This is what I see attempting to add their NuGet: Could not install package 'MuPDF.NET 1.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.